# running powershell with parameters in c# and writting those parameters in Text File

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run a powershell script in c#
here is the first test script

```
param(
[string] $computer,
[string] $password
)


out-file -filepath C:\File\parameter.txt -inputobject $computer -encoding ASCII -width 50 -Append
out-file -filepath C:\File\params.txt -inputobject $password -encoding ASCII -width 50 -Append
out-file -filepath C:\File\Sys32.txt -inputobject $password -encoding ASCII -width 50 -Append
```

and here is my C# supposed to run the powershellscript

```
     private void testRunningPowershell()
    {
        string mypass = gettingPass();

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            runspace.SessionStateProxy.Path.SetLocation("C:\\Users\\robert\\Desktop\\Titanium\\");

            RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            //runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

            // create a pipeline and feed it the script text (AddScript method) or use the filePath (Add method)
            using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline())
            {

                Command command = new Command(@"C:\Users\robert\Desktop\Titanium\Titanium2.ps1");
                dictionaryParams.Remove("FriendlyName");

                foreach (var item in dictionaryParams)
                {
                    if (item.Key == (string)comboBoxScreen.SelectedItem)
                    {
                        CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter(null, item.Value);
                        CommandParameter testParam2 = new CommandParameter(null, mypass);
                        command.Parameters.Add(null, testParam);
                        command.Parameters.Add(null, testParam2);
                    }
                }

                pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
                var results = pipeline.Invoke();

                ReturnInfo ri = new ReturnInfo();
                foreach (PSObject p in results)
                {
                    Hashtable ht = p.ImmediateBaseObject as Hashtable;

                    ri.ReturnText = (string)ht["ComputerName"];
                    ri.ReturnText = (string)ht["password"];
                }





                runspace.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

my purpose is to test if the cmdlet is run with the right parameters
I've got a windows form app that allow the user to choose the parameter
I would like to get my parameter value written in Text File (.txt)
instead I am getting this

```
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CommandParameter
```

instead of the parameter's value choosen

Comment: `Write-Host` does not return anything.

Comment: so if I changed my script like this,can I expect to see my parameters 
param like this var result=pipeline.invoke();or how can I know that my powershell is excuted ?
[string] $computer,
[string] $password
)


[hashtable]$Return = @{} 
$Return.ReturnCode = [int]1 
$Return.computerName = [string] $computer.ToString()
$Return.password = [string] $password.ToString()
Return $Return

Comment: I can see following problems in your code: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` — that command set execution policy in `LocalMachine` scope, which require admin rights (since it throw exception in case of failure, you have to notice that, if that was the problem). You never print or return `resutl` variable (so how did you know, that you have no results?). `runspace.Close` missing parenthesis and `();` missing method to invoke. After fixing all, your code work fine for me.